# Another rails mailer not working issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

First in my project, I can receive the registration confirmation email sent by devise gem and mandrill service. So I assume my email config settings are correct. However, my own `send_mail` function just cannot send email successfully.

My mailer settings:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
    password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
  }
  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  # Send email in development mode?
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Mailer Class:

```
class BidMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "service@xxx.com"

  def send_mail(bid)
    @bid = bid
    mail(to: 'xxxxx@gmail.com', subject: 'Bid Accepted', reply_to: 'service@xxx.com')
  end
end
```

In the controller I simply call `BidMailer.send_mail(bid).deliver`. I also have the html file for in the view for the email body.

I can see this in my server console log:

```
Sent mail to xxx@gmail.com (24.0ms)
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 22:39:45 +1100
From: service@xxx.com
Reply-To: service@xxx.com
To: xxx@gmail.com
Message-ID: <550029815f07_782a3fec29fa23c8413c@Shanes-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Bid Accepted
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

And also I can see similar email log when `devise` sends out registration confirm email.

But I totally dont get why I cannot get any email sent by my `send_mail` function?

Anyone could give some help? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Do you actually see the html template printed out in your server log? Also, this is probably not related but if you are using Rails 4 you'll want to use `.deliver_now` instead of `.deliver` as the latter is deprecated and on its way out.

Comment: Thanks. yes I could see the html template.

I am using rails 4.1. deliver_now was introduced in 4.2 i think.

Comment: Have you logged in to Heroku to verify that the email is actually being sent once it gets to them? Check the "Outbound" tab. It sounds like the problem might be there since everything on your side looks good

Comment: I am debugging this on my localhost, not heroku. Could I also check outbound somehow locally? Thanks

Comment: ugh, sorry, no idea why I typed Heroku. I meant to say Mandrill

Comment: thanks so much!! opened mandrill outbound and figured it out why. my mail server domain should be .com.au, not .com.